# Sorting with underscores

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I'm trying to sort a list of files so that underscore chars are considered "later" than other ascii characters as seen in the example below (this is porting external software to python3). I'd like the sorting to account for file paths in the same way it was originally as to produce no diffs with the original sorting.

Requirements: Avoid 3rd party sorting modules if possible

files = sorted( files, key=lambda d: d['name'].lower() )

Example re-ordering which I'm trying to avoid

```
-/usr/wte/wte_scripts/wfaping.sh
 /usr/wte/wte_scripts/wfa_test_cli.sh
+/usr/wte/wte_scripts/wfaping.sh
```

I've searched for similar examples of sorting and couldn't find anything concrete with the same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just replace `"_"` with a character that is "cosidered later" than letters (e.g. `"{"`, the first ASCII character after "z") in the key function:

```
sorted(files, key=lambda d: d["name"].lower().replace("_", "{"))
```

If a sorting collision between `"_"` and `"{"` is not acceptable, the solution would be to write a custom comparator function which imposes the desired order, and write the sorting algorithm yourself as python3 no longer supports supplying your own `cmp` function to `list.sort` or `sorted`.

Comment: I tried to find any documentation (even thought locale could be involved) on how strings are compared (the old data is sorted using the linux sort utility). Thanks for the tip which I hadn't though about but I'd like to know if there is a way to alter the default cmp function some other one that behaves the same as what I get from the linux sort utility.

Comment: According to `man sort` the order is determined by the Locale set on the machine, with `LC_ALL=C` resulting in the ASCII ordering (which is the default for python strings); your Locale probably differs from that and results in this nonstandard ordering. In python2, you could specify a `cmp` function instead of a `key` function with `sorted`, but it wasn't recommended as this would have been slower than `key`. In python3, you can't really change the built-in comparison of strings unless you patch the C unicode implementation or define your own unicode subclass which conforms to your ordering.

Comment: IMO, this is a hacky workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei it's not hacky for the stated requirement to simply sort `"_"` after letters (although it should probably use `"{"` instead of `"}"` as that's the first ASCII character after z). It has the obvious drawback that sorting cannot differentiate between `"_"` and `"{"`, which is probably not an issue in most cases and especially for sorting file names (OPs case). The "clean" solution of writing a custom string comparison function that imposes an order where `"_"` is in-between `"z"` and `"{"` would be massively overkill for most cases.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei ... and in python3, the "hacky workaround" is basically the only viable solution as you would otherwise need to write the whole sorting algorithm yourself too, not just the comparison function. So it's the only way that works with the built-in `sorted` method.

Comment: @l4mpi Good answer. You can also write a stateful class which generates a number based on where you want the `str`ing to go (eg. `"aaa"`=>`5`, `"A"`=>`7`, `"_x"`=>`6` will sort to `["aaa", "_x", "A"]`). Your class can also remember what number it generated for the other `str`ings so it can function like `cmp`.